# Error when parsing Yaml file - Cannot create property for JavaBean

Tags: java, jackson, yaml, snakeyaml

`Yaml` file contains:

```
test:
  subHeading: "1234"
```

**Model.java**

```
class Model{
  @JsonProperty("test")
  private SubHeading subHead;

  private class SubHeading{
     @JsonProperty("subHeading")
      private String text;
  }
```

I try to parse above `Yaml` content as follows:

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(Model.class));
System.out.println(yaml.load(new FileReader(PATH)).toString());
```

I immediately get an exception:

```
Cannot create property=test for JavaBean=Model@13a5fe33
 in 'reader', line 1, column 1:
    test:
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong and what I can change here?

Answer (score 2):

Fist of all you use `Jackson` annotation but `SnakeYaml` library to read a `yaml` file. You have to simplify your solution by:

1. Simplifying model
2. Use `Jackson`
3. Removing `Jackson` annotation in cases where properties have the same name as values in annotation.

**Model**
Create each class as `public class` in new file.

```
public class Model {

    private SubHeading test;

    public SubHeading getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(SubHeading test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Model{" +
                "test=" + test +
                '}';
    }
}
```

and

```
public class SubHeading {
    private String subHeading;

    public String getSubHeading() {
        return subHeading;
    }

    public void setSubHeading(String subHeading) {
        this.subHeading = subHeading;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SubHeading{" +
                "subHeading='" + subHeading + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory;

public class YamlTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        String text = "test:\n" +
                "  subHeading: \"1234\"";

        Model model = mapper.readValue(text, Model.class);
        System.out.println(model);
    }
}
```

Above prints:

```
Model{test=SubHeading{subHeading='1234'}}
```